# Shiny plotly : how to fix hidden hovermode tooltip at the top of the graph

Tags: css, r, shiny, plotly

I have a shiny app with a Plotly in the middle of the screen with multiple lines. I am using "x unified" hovermode, so when I put the cursor on the plot, I can see the value for each line. However, when I have a lot of lines, the tooltip of "hovermode" is cut at the top of the graph, and I am trying to make it entirely visible.

What I already tried and doesn't work:

- put a higher z-index on the graph ph
- add margin or padding to the graph, but the tooltip is still cut at the top of the graph

Any idea how I can fix this ?

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
  xvar = rep(1:5, each = 26),
  yvar = sample(1:100, 5*26, replace = TRUE),
  groupvar = rep(letters, 5)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$div(id = "my_div", style = "height:100px; background-color: blue; z-index: 0"),  
  plotlyOutput("my_plot") # I need the plot hovermode to be over the previous div 
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$my_plot <- renderPlotly({
    fig <- plot_ly(df, x = ~xvar, y = ~yvar, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines',
                   name = ~groupvar, color = ~groupvar)
    fig <- fig %>% layout(hovermode = "x unified")
    fig
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't affect the layout of your shiny app, increasing the height of the plot allows the hover label to stay within the borders and prevents overflow.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$div(id = "my_div", style = "height:100px; background-color: blue; z-index: 0"),  
  plotlyOutput("my_plot", height = "600px")
)
```

[image: Plot result]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the height of the plots, because in my apps there are a lots of others output